# How do I add IPv6 address into System32\drivers\etc\hosts?

Tags: windows, ipv6, hosts-file, domain-name-system

There is already by default, and it works (Win 7):

```
::1             localhost
```

This also works (testing with ping):

```
::1             hosta
```

But when I'm trying to add something non-loopback, it doesn't resolve:

```
fe80::215:afff:fec6:ea64 realhost
```

So that I can do:

```
C:>ping fe80::215:afff:fec6:ea64
Reply from fe80::215:afff:fec6:ea64: time=2ms
```

But can't go with hostname that I put in hosts:

```
C:>ping realhost
Ping request could not find host realhost. ...
```

Any way to add an IPv6 address to hosts in Windows?

Comment: Is that LL address on the same network?

Comment: Yes, as you may have noticed fe80:: in it. Ping just cant find IP for realhost.

Comment: Hold on a moment. If you can't ping that ip address then fiddling about with hosts files isn't going to help you.

Comment: There's nothing stopping someone from SSHing to a remote host, reading the LL address there, and putting it in their `hosts` file. Except that won't work, because it's a LL address.

Comment: I can `ping fe80::215:afff:fec6:ea64` directly. But can't `ping realhost`. This is the problem. System cannot resolve realhost using hosts record.

Comment: Try to specify FDQN name with hostname, e.g.

    fec0::fa3:2aa:ff:fe9f:2a40      webv6.central.example.com w1

Comment: That was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 26):

Finally, I've found the way. I speicied zone ID (**11** in my case) in hosts:

```
fe80::215:afff:fec6:ea64%11 realhost
```

Which I've got using

```
netsh interface ipv6 show addresses
```

With help of http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726995.aspx

Comment: Hey, that command... did you have to run it on the realhost machine?

Asking because I got an IPv4 IP for that realhost, but we cannot connect to it and we don't even know where it's hosted. So trying to find out that %11 or similar in any other way... :S

Answer (score 5):

Try like this is host file of window. Hope it can help

**`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`**:

```
[2001:db8::10:2aa:ff:fe21:5a88] tsrvv6.wcoast.example.com
```

Comment: it doesn`t work

Answer (score 4):

According to a Microsoft TechNet article from 2005/2006:

> You should not place entries for
>   link-local addresses in the Hosts file
>   because you cannot specify the zone ID
>   for those addresses. This concept is
>   similar to using the Ping tool to ping
>   a link-local destination without
>   specifying the zone ID. Therefore,
>   entries in the Hosts file are useful
>   only for global or site-local IPv6
>   addresses.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx

Comment: If I put what they do `2001:db8::10:2aa:ff:fe21:5a88  tsrvv6.wcoast.example.com ts1`. It doesn't get resolved when I try to `ping tsrvv6.wcoast.example.com`. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Win7 nearby so can't test it, but I got caught by the hosts.sam file  once. Windows Explorer will hide extensions by default, so I spent a day editing the "hosts" file but it was actually the hosts.sam file. Make sure you are editing the real hosts file.

And antispyware programs will block changes to the hosts file. Malware will add hosts entries to redirect bank websites to fake sites.

Adding ipv6 addresses to the hosts file does work on W2K8, I did it last week.

Comment: The hosts.sam file is the real hosts file. You need to remove the .sam extension when you use it. The same goes for the lmhosts.sam file.

Comment: maybe on some systems. usually i've seen a hosts file and a hosts.sam file. But i'm usually fixing other people's boxes.

Comment: ".sam" is ".sample" in 8.3 dos compatible file names :-)